# ListView DisplayMemberBinding vs. DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listview

Can I use DisplayMemberBinding and still be able to define a DataTemplate for the Datatype of that column. As soon as I set the DisplayMemberBinding for a column that column ony can display simple text. But I don't want text :)
But if I use Celltemplate all cells of that column use the same DataTemplate. But I don't want the same template for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically choose the template based on the item, you will need to use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplateselector.aspx):

```
<GridViewColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyCellTemplateSelector"/>
```